# Legal to publish video of sports competitions without subjects' consent?

Tags: united-kingdom, photography, sport

If I participate in and film my participation in a sports competition in the UK, can I publish the footage afterwards if it contains the other participants without asking them?

Comment: What kind of sports competition? Who sponsors it? Is the game under the auspices of a licensed league? Is it on public or private land?

Comment: Are the competitors adults?

Comment: Related https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/82872/is-it-legal-to-own-a-photo-of-someone-and-spread-it-around-without-their-permiss/82881#82881